# Hibernate error: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: model.Room

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, orm

## Solved - Updated

I deleted merge user method and adding room to room list from the user.

```
public void save(Room room, User user) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        room.getUsers().add(user);
        session.merge(room);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

And updating the user instance out the RoomRepository to get the updated User instance:

```
public void updateUser() {
    this.user = userRepository.updateUser(user);
}
```

On UserRepository:

```
public User updateUser(User user) {
    User result = null;
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        result = session.get(User.class, user.getId());
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Probably this is a bad practise, so I'll have to think how to refactor this.

---

## Problem

I have class Room and class User with a ManyToMany association.

### User

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "users")
public Set<Room> rooms = new HashSet<>();
```

### Room

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "sala_usuario",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_salas"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cod_user"))
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

This is the exception's trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: model.Room
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:161)
at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:374)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.list(QuerySqmImpl.java:1073)
at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:94)
at repository.MessageRepository.findRoomMessages(MessageRepository.java:41)
at app.ChatController.loadMessages(ChatController.java:123)
at app.ChatController.lambda$initialize$0(ChatController.java:45)
```

This is the save method in RoomRepository:

```
public void save(Room room, User user) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            user.getRooms().add(room);
            room.getUsers().add(user);
            session.merge(room);
            session.merge(user);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
}
```

The error happens when a Room is opened by the user and try to get the messages with OneToMany association because the instance of Room is not persisted on Hibernate, but it is:

```
public List<Message> findRoomMessages(Room room) {
        List<Message> result = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<Message> query = cb.createQuery(Message.class);
            Root<Message> root = query.from(Message.class);
            query.select(root).where(cb.equal(root.get("room"), room));
            result = session.createQuery(query).getResultList();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I've solved making this, but I want to use ORM:

```
public List<Message> findRoomMessages(Room room) {
        List<Message> result = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            result = session.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM mensajes WHERE id_sala = :pid_sala", Message.class)
                            .setParameter("pid_sala", room.getId()).list();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about it and I'm absolutely no hibernate expert but I think you could give it a try.

```
public void save(Room room, User user) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        try {
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            room.getUsers().add(user); //it shouldn't be needed to add the room to the users rooms
            session.merge(room);//the save operation should be cascaded, so the user should be automatically saved as well
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
}
```

Comment: It's true, session.merge(room) create the Room and update the User on cascade. Thinking about that i've discovered what was happening on my program. The instance of User used on parameters wasn't being updated, so I made a method updateUser to recover updated User's instance from ORM using session.get(User.class, user.getId()) and returning this object. Maybe it's a bad practise, so I will have to check the program.
Thanks a lot!